# Telegram API-vendor/autoload.php

Tags: php, telegram-bot

I want to integrate a telegram API in PHP.
I refereed following link
  https://github.com/funcoding/TelegramPHPBot/blob/master/README.md
I installed composer on my machine but i am not able to generate 
vendor/autoload.php file.
I am new to this. can anyone give me solution.

Comment: What command did you run?

Comment: I add following line in composer.json {
    "require": {
        "curiouscoder/telegram-php-bot": "dev-master"
    }
}

Comment: `vendor/autoload.php` will be created automatically for you when you run `composer update` after changing `composer.json`. Make sure your current directory is the directory in which your `composer.json` exists. Make sure you're running the command with write access to the folder (either through sudo or an elevated command prompt)

Answer (score 0):

After creating the `composer.json` file run `composer install` command to install the dependencies. This will create a `vendor` folder where you can find `autoload.php` file.

Comment: We have already installed composer. But vendor folder does not get created.

Comment: After you install composer open terminal/cmd and type `composer --version`, the output must be something like this `Composer version 1.0-dev (44bc8e0...) 2015-12-07 16:56:35`. This means you have successfully installed composer. Then create composer.json file. From terminal/cmd navigate to composer.json file directory and run `composer install`.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow below steps for install `Telegram API`:

1. Download `master.zip` file. Extract zip file into your local `wamp`
   server.
2. Open your `cmd` and then go to your `wamp` directory using `cd wamp` and `cd www`.
3. Then go to your `Telegram API` directory using `cd Telegram API`
4. Then run `composer install` command from `command prompt`
5. Now you can see `vendor` folder in your `Telegram API` directory after finish installation.

No need to edit `composer.json` file.

See below screenshot

[image]

---

**Composer.json** code

```
{
    "name": "curiouscoder/telegram-php-bot",
    "description": "Telegram Bot API written in PHP",
    "keywords": ["telegram-bot", "telegram", "bot", "api"],
    "type": "library",
    "require": {
      "php": ">=5.4",
      "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "5.3.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "CuriousCoder\\TelegramBot\\": "src"
        }
    },
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Vinay Kumar",
            "email": "vinaykumar1989@gmail.com",
        "role": "Developer"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

Comment: Please Provide a link for Telegram API library which you have mentioned above.because i tried four libraries.

Comment: Here is library link : https://github.com/funcoding/TelegramPHPBot You already mention in your question

Comment: As you told i got success in creating vendor/autoload.php file. I am not getting what to do next. I have created my bot with the help of botfather. Generated my api key. Integrated in my php code. I am able to chat with mybot. Is it possible to make a chat between different users?